# Расположение в компоненте div

Tags: html, css

Есть небольшой пример со списком задач.

1. Как сделать, чтобы кнопки для удаления задачи были справа, но внутри `div.task-view`, т.е. были максимально(или почти) приближены к правой границе `div.task-view`?
2. Как обвести в рамку `div.task-view`?

```css
body{
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.task-view label{
  display: inline;
}

.remove-task {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header>Todo</header>
<div class="add-task">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>
    add task
  </button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="task-view">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <label>One</label>
      <button class="remove-task">X</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task-view">
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      <label>Two</label>
      <button class="remove-task">X</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Вот [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/vmokhae9/) на пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способов много, один из них - сделать контейнер в котором лежит кнопка удаления и соседние с ней элементы флекс контейнером.

```
.task-view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

После этого внутри этого контейнера будут работать правила разметки по флекс боксам. Теперь можно для кнопки задать отступ слева со значением auto, что отодвинет её максимально вправо.

```
.remove-task {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
```

Ну а рамка просто задаётся таким образом, толщину и цвет, само собой можно менять:

```
.task-view {
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
}
```

`cornflowerblue` - это просто название цвета. Можно использовать любой другой цвет, например `#c2c2c2` или `red`.

```css
body {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*Даём отступ вниз в 10px всем li, кроме последнего*/
li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}


/*Делаем из task-view флекс-контейнер*/
.task-view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
}

.task-view label {
  display: inline;
}


/*С помощью margin-left: auto; отодвигаем крестик вправо.*/
.remove-task {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>Todo</header>
<div class="add-task">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>
    add task
  </button>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="task-view">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>One</label>
      <button class="remove-task">X</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task-view">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>Two</label>
      <button class="remove-task">X</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Извините за уточнение, как вам кажется - вопрос топикастера, на который вы ответили, не совсем качественный?

Comment: @0xdb В каком-то смысле может и не качественный) Но суть вопроса я вроде понял, потому и ответил)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Просто спросил потому, что вы ответили, ответ был принят, но вы не проголосовали за вопрос. Это обычно значит - вопрос очень низкого качества и должен бытъ закрыт.

Comment: @0xdb Я о таком не знал, спасибо, теперь буду в курсе)